# How to set up Ubuntu 15.04 for professional CSGO

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

Basically what I'm looking to do is set up an OS this one happens to be the one I chose because it has the best community and less scary windows-centered security concerns but I'm having a few noticeable issues from the gate.

1.) Frame Drops - I understand frames wont be the same, but I'd at least like to get around the 200 area

2.) Mouse options - I need to figure out either how to install my mouse software or how to easily change the mouse dpi AND TURNING OFF MOUSE ACCEL ALL TOGETHER

3.) Nvidia Settings - On windows I usually go in the nvidia control panel and play with the digital vibrance, gamma, and some of the aliasing settings and other little things as well as set my monitor to 144hz manually. All of which things I don't know how to do on Ubuntu and would like to learn.

If you could teach me anything at all I would sincerely appreciate it, because I really want to learn I just don't know where to go for these types of questions other than forums, and so far had not had much luck. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I see that there is a linux version, but it's not as easy as just installing the game. There are other things that need to be done as well

Comment: Did you set up the nvidia proprietary drivers? That will make quite a difference in Framerate. And it will make it possible to use the nvidia settings, too.

Comment: There is an official documentation on the drivers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: @ApolloLV I will have to try that to make sure I installed the nvidia driver properly and have the appropriate headers, thank you for the official documentation!

Answer (score 0):

1) Depend on your type of card and how much effort valve put in to optimize the game, results may vary, but from my experience nvidia card give pretty good performance with cs go, just search additional driver in the dash and install nvidia driver from there and you're good to go

2) To turn off mouse acceleration completely, search startup application and add new entry there

> Name: Disable mouse accel
>   Command: xset m 1 0 (1: base speed of your mouse - equivalent 6/11 on windows , you can lower it if you like; 0: turn off mouse accel)

3) Once you installed nvidia driver, just search nvidia in the dash, open nvidia then navigate to CRT-1, it's just below Powermizer, on control tab in CRT -1 you can set Digital Vibrance, gamma and brightness on color correction tab